# Query on Address object

Tags: apex

Can anyone tell me how to write query on Address standard object?

I am trying to query on Address object but getting eror.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the code you are using and the verbatim error message. Note that `Address` is only available with specific packages/features (Field Service Lightning).

Answer (score 2):

Address can be an object or a field Type. Do you refer to the object? if not...

That field type is currently in the way to become GA for us to use, but don't wait up, they estimate the release around Winter '22 [[source]](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVWAA0)

The address type is what they call a compound field, so if what you want is to query the fields inside the address, apart from using the field itself you have plenty of sub-fields. You can find the list and more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm).

(to sum-up if the field is called `BillingAddress` and you want to query the sub-field `Street`, you need to query for `BillingStreet` there is a sub-field ca

Answer (score 1):

The [Address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_address.htm) object is only available if Field Service Lightning is enabled. Make sure you have this feature and its enabled for your profile.

Answer (score 0):

I used Schema.Address and it worked.
If you want to use Address object then you have to use Schema.Address.
For compound Address field use System.Address